# How to check SharedPreferences key if not empty or null?

Tags: flutter

How to check SharedPreferences key if empty or null?

when i run the program it give me an error
[image]

```
1.]  Future<String> getStrings() async {
2.]   Future<SharedPreferences> _sPrefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
3.]   final SharedPreferences prefs = await _sPrefs;
4.]   appid = prefs.getString('appid');
5.]   print(appid);
6.]   if (appid != '') {
7.]    return appid;
8.]  }
9.] return ''; }
```

Above is my code, the error is only showing when i run my logout function that has `prefs.clear()`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `(appid != '')` to `(appid != null)`. Null and an empty string are different things.

You can shorten this using a null-aware operator to:

```
return appid ?? '';
```